# Filter and Sort the List with Caml Query

Tags: caml-query, jsom, caml

We are required to display the list data based on below 3 conditions for the based on 3 columns (Customer Category, Test Type ,Exercise Result) and sort with column (stage Plan) .

```
       1.  Customer Category : 0,1,1d,2,5

       2.  Test Type is equal to : "TableTop" (It is Choice Control)

       3.   Exercise Result is : Null or blank

       4.   And finally sort the list-view with Column "stage Plan".
```

Can any one help me how can I get the result based using CAML QUery

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but should something like:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Test Type' /><Value Type='Text'>TableTop</Value></Eq>
         <And>
           <IsNull><FieldRef Name='Exercise Result' /></IsNull>
           <And>
              <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Customer Category' /><Value Type='Text'>0</Value></Eq>
                  <Or>
                   <Eq><FieldRef Name='Customer Category' /><Value Type='Text'>1</Value></Eq>
                   <Or>
                     <Eq><FieldRef Name='Customer Category' /><Value Type='Text'>1d</Value></Eq>
                     <Or>
                       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Customer Category' /><Value Type='Text'>2</Value></Eq>
                       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Customer Category' /><Value Type='Text'>5</Value></Eq>
                    </Or>
                 </Or>
              </Or>
           </And>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
   <OrderBy>
     <FieldRef Name='stage Plan' Ascending='TRUE' />
   </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

You can check the CAML builder: https://www.u2u.be/software

Answer (score 0):

Update column names:

```
    <Query>
       <Where>
          <And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Test Type' /><Value Type='Text'>TableTop</Value></Eq>
             <And>
               <IsNull><FieldRef Name='Exercise Result' /></IsNull>
               <And>
                   <In>
                      <FieldRef Name="Customer Category"/>
                      <Values>
                        <Value Type="Text">0</Value>
                        <Value Type="Text">1</Value>
                        <Value Type="Text">1d</Value>
                        <Value Type="Text">2</Value>
                        <Value Type="Text">5</Value>
                      </Values>
                    </In>
               </And>
             </And>
          </And>
       </Where>
       <OrderBy>
         <FieldRef Name='stage Plan' Ascending='TRUE' />
       </OrderBy>
    </Query>
```